# Get number of pages in PDF via ViewerJS

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

Using [ViewerJS](https://viewerjs.org/) is it possible to get the number of pages in the PDF document being displayed?

I can see from the `pdf.js` file that comes with ViewerJS that there is `data.numPages` but I simply cannot figure out how access it.

One solution (which I don't like, but works) is to get the `<span id="numPages" class="toolbarLabel">of 12</span>` and parse the inner text...

```js
var text = document.getElementById("numPages").innerText;
var numPages = parseInt(text.match(/^of (\d+)/i)[1], 10);
console.log(numPages);
```

```html
<span id="numPages" class="toolbarLabel">of 12</span>
```

Can anybody point me to how to get the value from the ViewerJS data, rather than the horrible solution above?

Please also be aware that the ViewerJS is being displayed within an `<iframe>`, but that should't make any difference to the answer as it's same-domain, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you could count the `.page` elements to get the total number of pages, like so:

```
iframe.contentWindow.document.querySelectorAll('.page').length
```

Comment: Excellent, out of the box thinking, I like it... Thanks